# How to display a sweet alert box when submission is completed sucessfully in laravel 5?

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5, sweetalert

I want to display a sweet alert after clicking the submit button and if all the validations are correct. I have done the validations using Request class.How can I do that?

Comment: I wasn't aware of SweetAlert as a proper noun. I just thought you wanted to display some sweet-looking alerts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presuming you're using the sweetalert Facade ([Laravel package](https://github.com/uxweb/sweet-alert)), something like should do the trick:

```
if ($validator->fails()) {
    //handle your validation errors
} else {
    //validation was succesful show sweetalert and return 
    Alert::success('Success Message', 'Optional Title');
    return Redirect::home();
}
```

To install the sweetalert laravel wrapper use composer like any other package:

```
composer require uxweb/sweet-alert
```

then set up the aliases in laravels config/app.php

Providers:

```
'providers' => [

    /*
     * Laravel Framework Service Providers...
     */
    ...
    'UxWeb\SweetAlert\SweetAlertServiceProvider',

],
```

Aliases:

```
'aliases' => [
    ...
    'Alert'         => 'UxWeb\SweetAlert\SweetAlert',

],
```

Download the [sweetalert files](http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/) and place them in your public directory and link to them from your layout files.

Include the default layout in your laravel master template as in the github documentation

```
@include('sweet::alert')
```

You should now be good to go.

Custom View (alertcancel.blade.php)

```
@if (Session::has('sweet_alert.alert'))
    <script>
        swal({
            text: "{!! Session::get('sweet_alert.text') !!}",
            title: "{!! Session::get('sweet_alert.title') !!}",
            timer: {!! Session::get('sweet_alert.timer') !!},
            type: "{!! Session::get('sweet_alert.type') !!}",
            showConfirmButton: "{!! Session::get('sweet_alert.showConfirmButton') !!}",
            confirmButtonText: "{!! Session::get('sweet_alert.confirmButtonText') !!}",
            confirmButtonColor: "#AEDEF4",
            showCancelButton: true
            // more options
        });
    </script>
@endif
```

In your master template include the custom view: @include ('alertcancel')

[sweetalert's github examples](https://github.com/uxweb/sweet-alert/blob/master/readme.md)

[Laravel's Validation Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/master/validation)

Comment: if you install the package I've linked to in my answer and set up its alias and its providers (a guide is available if you follow the sweetalert's github examples link, it's installed via composer like any other package) then yes Alert is a reference to the sweetalert wrapper package and it will handle displaying the alert for you.

Comment: I'll need to see some code or atleast get a thorough description of what you've done and what you see.

If i had to guess I'd say that you've probably forgotten to include the layout file in your master layout.

refer to the github link and search for the following line: "@include('sweet::alert')"

Comment: To achieve this I think you're going to need to use a custom view, there is an example on the github page of what it should/could look like.

Using a custom view and the 'showCancelButton: true,' sweet alert configuration you should be able to achieve what you're trying to.

Comment: After moving into custom view, how to change the @include('sweet::alert'). Because nothing change when displaying.

Comment: Create a custome view that uses the showCancelButton: true config option. Call the custom view alert.cancel.blade.php

Now include this custom view in your main template instead of the default one (alert.blade.php)

Comment: please can you further explain me above comment. It is not clear.

Comment: @R.Zoom I've edited my answer to try and make it more clear

Comment: Where to locate the file alert.cancel.blade.php? Is it inside view directory. I have no idea creating a custom view.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105581/discussion-between-joe1992-and-r-zoom).

Answer (score 0):

You can download SweetAlert files from here: http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/

```js
document.querySelector('button#test-1').onclick = function() {
  swal("Here's a message!");
};
document.querySelector('button#test-2').onclick = function() {
  swal({
    title: "Sweet!",
    text: "Here's a custom image.",
    imageUrl: "https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/best-hand/500/Hand_finger_like_thumbs_up-512.png"
  })
};
document.querySelector('button#test-3').onclick = function() {
  swal({
    title: "Are you sure?",
    text: "Your will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
    type: "warning",
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
    confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!"
  });
};
document.querySelector('button#test-4').onclick = function() {
  swal("Oops...", "Something went wrong!", "error");
};
```

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather:300,700);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather+Sans:300,700);
 * {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
  background: #00000;
  font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
  color: #efefef;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 1.5;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
a,
a:visited {
  color: #00000;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 1em auto;
  padding: 2em 3em;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid #FFFFF;
}
h1 {
  font-family: 'Merriweather Sans', sans-serif;
}
button {
  padding: 0.4em 0.8em;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  border-radius: 25px;
  font-family: 'Merriweather Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 300;
  background: #sdfs8;
  box-shadow: none;
  border: 1px solid #90AABF;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://tristanedwards.me/u/SweetAlert//lib/sweet-alert.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://tristanedwards.me/u/SweetAlert//lib/sweet-alert.css">


<div class="wrapper">
  <p>
    <button id="test-1">Basic</button>
    <button id="test-2">Success</button>
    <button id="test-3">Fancy</button>
    <button id="test-4">Error</button>
    <p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>

</div>
```